Why is my bathtub floor uneven?
My bathtub floor is extremely uneven. Is this just poor refinishing or a sign that it's rusted through?


I'd say it's both. Refinishing was attempted to repair damaged porcelain without any filling of the chips or other preparation. Now you're seeing eruptions caused by subsurface rust.
Either that or the finish was bubbly or otherwise not smooth on application, or the tub surface wasn't cleaned well prior. You'll have to investigate further, which of course could result in damage.

Typically rust beneath a finish will cause the finish to bubble up.  You look to have mostly depression (it's not clear if the non-smooth flaws are raised or depressed).
